# Browser will send my cookie

Tags: php, cookies, browser

PHP will store the cookie from my special web page after login. (php setcookie). It will received from server. However, when I make a http post request the cookie will not send back to my server. Should browser send the cookie automatically to server?

Comment: Check the cookie domain and path if it matches yours.

Answer (score 0):

> Should browser send the cookie automatically to server?

Yes, but only if:

- the cookie didn't expire
- the cookie is set in the right domain/subdomain/path
- the cookie is not flagged as `httpOnly` if the POST request is made via AJAX
- the cookie is not flagged as `secure` if the POST request is made unencrypted via HTTP (not HTTPS)